# How to get name of current folder only, for new folder on same level?

Tags: cmd.exe

Let's say I have a folder called "Demos" on a path, and I would like to use ONLY that "Demos" folder name to create a new folder on the same level but with " (Downloads)" added. Would it be something like **MD "..\%CD% (Downloads)"**, or have I got the wrong variable?

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the output?  What did you expect the output to be?  Edit your question.

Comment: I expected the output to be "Demos (Downloads)", and the above example did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution elsewhere and modified it, the code that works is:

@FOR %%* IN (.) DO SET DLDIR=%%~NX*
@MD "..\%DLDIR% (Downloads)"

However, DON'T try something like:

SET DLDIR=%CD% (Downloads)

Because when I did this, I totally corrupted my Downloads folder.